# Getting a connection to MongoDB database from URL with db name in it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB connection string with the DB included.  I am currently initializing the collection this way:

```
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(_connectionString);
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
var mongoDatabase = mongoServer.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
_defaultCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Comment>("comments");
```

This works fine but just seems longer than it should be.  Am I missing a less chatty way of doing the same thing?

Thanks
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you're **not missing out** on a thing - it's indeed a cumbersome way of achieving a common task.

I would encourage you to have a look at the excellent open source [MongoRepository](http://mongorepository.codeplex.com/) project which makes such simple tasks a breeze.

Comment: OK great.  It is not a big deal as most of it gets written once in a base class and then pretty much ignored...it just seemed like I must be missing something.